# AnulgarJS - Object parameters in service not changing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, service, constants

I'm having some troubles with services in angular.

Basically I have a service that I use as a constant class for user specific parameters, I store these in variables that read the values from a cookie.

This is my service:

```
shoutApp.service('userConfig', function (userService, config) {
this.USER_ID = $.cookie('shoutUserObj')._id;
this.USER_USERNAME = $.cookie('shoutUserObj').username;
this.USER_PASSWORD = $.cookie('shoutUserObj').password;
this.USER_JOINDATE = $.cookie('shoutUserObj').joinDate;
this.USER_TWITTER = $.cookie('shoutUserObj').twitter;
this.USER_FACEBOOK = $.cookie('shoutUserObj').facebook;
this.USER_GOOGLE = $.cookie('shoutUserObj').google;

this.refreshUserObj = function (callback) {
    console.log("Starting refresh");
    //This function retrieves new user data
    userService.requestUserObj($.cookie('shoutUserObj')._id, function (code, userObj) {
        if (code === config.CODE_AJAX_SUCCESS) {
            //Here I delete the old cookie and set a new one with the same name
            $.removeCookie('shoutUserObj');
            $.cookie.json = true;
            $.cookie('shoutUserObj', userObj, { path: '/', expires: 7 });
            //When I log the new values of the cookie at this point they changed
        }
    });
}
});
```

I also tried storing these in an object, but every time I change the paramters they only change inside the class ( Like when i log out the new variables in my refresh function, they changed, but when I try to access them from a controller through the return values, they are not changed).

Example Controller:

```
shoutApp.controller('profileController', function ($scope, config, userConfig) {
  console.log("Username: " + userConfig.USER_USERNAME);
  //This value allways stays the same, even when I changed the cookie
});
```

My goal is to get the changed paramteres in all my Controllers that use the user service, how can I achieve this?

Would be really thankful for any help!

Comment: Your question/code sample does not provide a complete enough picture of what your setup looks like. Please take a look at [**this working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/XCHU1d3PqBoB3mm7sa0M?p=preview) and consider an update to your question (and possibly a fork of the Plunker) which better demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Services are singletons, therefore the values of your `userConfig` properties will always have the values they had when the service was initialized.

In the service, use a function if you want to retrieve a new value each time

```
    this.getUSER_USERNAME = function() {
        return $.cookie('shoutUserObj').username;
    }
```

instead of a property

```
    this.USER_USERNAME = $.cookie('shoutUserObj').username;
```

then the example controller would be:

```
shoutApp.controller('profileController', function ($scope, config, userConfig) {
  console.log("Username: " + userConfig.getUSER_USERNAME());
  //This will return the current value of the cookie
});
```